# Java Spring MVC: Request processing failed - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, gradle

I'm encountering an issue with my Spring MVC application where I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR 7888 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]
> : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with
> path [] threw exception [Request processing failed:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument of type
> [java.lang.String] not specified, and parameter name information not
> available via reflection. Ensure that the compiler uses the
> '-parameters' flag.] with root cause

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```java
@RestController
public class TodoResource {
    private static final List<Todo> TODOS_LIST = List.of(new Todo("lol1","lol1"),
            new Todo("lol2","lol2"));
    @GetMapping("/todos")
    public List<Todo> retriveAllTodos() {
        return TODOS_LIST;
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{u1}/todos")
    public Todo retriveTodosForSpecificUser(@PathVariable String u1) {
        return TODOS_LIST.get(0);
    }
}
record Todo(String u1, String description) {}
```

Comment: Please share the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 3):

You need to add name to `@PathVariable`:

```java
@RestController
public class TodoResource {
    private static final List<Todo> TODOS_LIST = List.of(new Todo("lol1","lol1"),
            new Todo("lol2","lol2"));
    @GetMapping("/todos")
    public List<Todo> retriveAllTodos() {
        return TODOS_LIST;
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{u1}/todos")
    public Todo retriveTodosForSpecificUser(@PathVariable(name = "u1") String u1) {
        return TODOS_LIST.get(0);
    }
}
record Todo(String u1, String description) {}
```